# How to prevent CognitoUser from performing CRUD on another user's data in DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I basically need users to only be allowed to CRUD their own data in my app. Their data is stored in dynamodb and Im using cognito with amplify for a react native project.

I've searched for a lot of answers and most of them mention using the `identityID` as the primary/hash key in the item for dynamodb table. So I implemented it like so.

```
  import { API, Auth } from "aws-amplify";

  const createItemDB = async () => {
    API.post("nutritionAPI", "/items", {
      body: {
        userID: `${(await Auth.currentUserCredentials()).identityId}`,
        dateID: "february23",
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
          .getIdToken()
          .getJwtToken()}`,
      },
    })
      .then((result) => {
        // console.log(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Code below was default code from REST API I added through amplify.
`amplify/backend/function/src/app.js`

```
app.post(path, function(req, res) {
  if (userIdPresent) {
    req.body['userId'] = req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId || UNAUTH;
  }
  let putItemParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: req.body
  }
  dynamodb.put(putItemParams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.json({error: err, url: req.url, body: req.body});
    } else {
      res.json({success: 'post call succeed!', url: req.url, data: data})
    }
  });
});
```

I've blindly followed some guide on this topic and created a  Federated Identities Pool and linked it with my user pool, but not sure how it plays a part yet. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Does https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html help?

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT: updating the solution to fit Cognito instead of IAM users

I'm just putting hunterhacker's comment as an answer, because it really helped me.

Basically, IAM policy condition supports DynamoDB fine-grained access control, as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/).

Therefore, just need to make sure that the IAM Role associated with the Cognito users has this policy condition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToOnlyItemsMatchingUserID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/xyz"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}" <==== This part here!
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

From the article,

> This policy limits access to DynamoDB rows by checking the value of cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub. This value is the identity ID for the unique Amazon Cognito user.

Comment: if my partition key is exactly `userID` in my dynamodb table, then should it be `"${www.amazon.com:userID}"`. I tried this but it doesnt quite work. Also, in my identity pool, if I set the `Authenticated Role` to the IAM role with such policy, i get a 403 error.

Comment: im also wondering if i need to to change the `Authenticated role selection` from `use default role` to `choose roles with token` in the identity pool settings ?

Comment: No, don't change to `userID`. `www.amazon.com:user_id` refers to the Amazon User ID. The `dynamodb:LeadingKeys` refers to your partition key, whatever its name is. In this case, you don't need `choose roles with token`. That is to dynamically choose different role. In this case, this single role is sufficient, because the value of `www.amazon.com:user_id` is dynamic based on the user ID. I just realized you are using Cognito, not IAM users. So it should be `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub`. Editing the answer and the reference link.

Comment: I updated the policy but I get a 403 error. Perhaps I am querying my dynamodb incorrectly? Right now, I am calling an endpoint in the REST api (gateway api), which then queries the dynamodb table. Maybe my credentials are not authorized to access the api endpoint? Im not too sure but that is what i am suspecting. Should I be querying dynamodb without going through the api?

Comment: You seem to be in the right direction. If you are using API gateway, maybe try calling the DynamoDB api directly. And the policy above is for authenticated Cognito users. Are you logged into Cognito, or just using IAM user? IAM user will have separate permissions. Double-check this.

Comment: So thats what Im confused about too. Im pretty sure I am logged in as a cognito user when i am testing my app. However, my cognito user pool is also associated with the identity pool. I created a role with the attached policy. In that role, I have selected cognito as the provider and pasted the identity pool id. I found the guide i was following. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/

Comment: after playing around with the identity pool, changing the `authenticated role` to some auto generated role allows full access. so i assume i need to modify the above policy to also include access to my gateway api?

Comment: If you have an API Gateway to proxy your DynamoDB, the API Gateway has its own IAM Role. So `cognito user` --calls--> `API GW` --calls--> `DynamoDB`. Cognito user `authenticated role` just needs access to API GW. API GW role needs access to DynamoDB. This is likely not what you want. Why do you need API GW? Possible to just use DynamoDB without API GW?

Comment: Quite frankly im not sure why i use api gw, other than its a documented solution for querying dynamo from an amplify project. it was auto configured when i performed `amplify add api` (REST).  i guess im trying to learn the serverless approach of using amplify. i assume if i query dynamo without api gw, i would need a backend and amplify would then be unnecessary.

Comment: so im able to resolve the 403 error...but now i still have the problem of being able to delete another user's data. with more testing, the user is still able to `delete` even if i removed `"dynamodb:DeleteItem",` from the policy